# how to De-serialize the JSON file by c#

Tags: c#, python, json

if the key is different, how do i deserialize the JSON file, key from key1 to keyN  ? when i using python it's very easy, 
`import pandas as pd`
`myJson = pd.json.loads(json)` 
just used two lines code, but when i use C#, it's very hard to me. thanks.

i tried: 
1. visual studio -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as Classes, it will generate many class for every item key, which is too bad for me, because my key maybe from key1 to key 1000.

```
 public class Rootobject
{
  public Key1 key1 { get; set; }
  public Key2 key2 { get; set; }
  public Key3 key3 { get; set; }
 }
```

2.now i used below method, but i still think it's not easy as python.

```
JObject items = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var item in items)
{
         JObject v = JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString());
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in v)
            {  //do something}

 }
```

json string:

```
{
    "key1":
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"i",
        "AllocationInfo":
          {
                "State":"Init",
                "Name":"test",
                "TModel":
                    {
                        "Name":"test2",
                          "key":"1232445",
                            "v":{
                                       "id":"090",
                                        "Name":"tom"     
                                    }
                        }
            }
    },
"key2":
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"i",
        "AllocationInfo":
          {
                "State":"Init",
                "Name":"test",
                "TModel":
                    {
                        "Name":"test2",
                          "key":"1232445",
                            "v":{
                                       "id":"090",
                                        "Name":"tom"     
                                        }
                        }
            }
    },
"key3":
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"i",
        "AllocationInfo":
          {
                "State":"Init",
                "Name":"test",
                "TModel":
                    {
                        "Name":"test2",
                          "key":"1232445",
                            "v":  {
                                       "id":"090",
                                        "Name":"tom",     
                                        "D":{"id":"7890"}
                                        }
                        }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 3 objects in your json so this will be represented with classes, there is no other way to deserialize it to classes. If you can change the json, represent it as Array of keys you will have only one Key Class and the root object will be `List<Key>`

Comment: thanks for your reply, this Json is just a test file, my real Json is more complex than it.  at the same time I used your mentioned method in another class, but for this json string, I want to figure out  a  more easier way like python's json.loads() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DeserializeObject and get a dictionary from it:

```
var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Key>>(txt);
```

Declare your classes:

```
public class Key
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public AllocationInfo AllocationInfo { get; set; }
}

public class AllocationInfo
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TModel TModel { get; set; }
}


public class TModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public v v { get; set; }
}

public class v
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's great.  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Key>>(txt); i tried it before, but failed; just now  it succeeded. i will try it in my real project. maybe it's not simple as python, but it's enough now.

Answer (score 1):

You pasted the entire json when you used the paste special. But I think you only want to generate one class for all your keyN objects. You can then just use Newtonsoft to deserialize the json to a list.

```csharp
var myKeys = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyN>>(json);
```

Comment: @martineau very thanks. I figure out another way to solve this problem.